# Can we fetch specific rows using Hadoop Cassandra and Pig

Tags: cassandra, apache-pig

I am working on combination of hadoop, pig and cassandra. I want to fetch specific rows from cassandra using pig.  I am trying to access the cassandra from pig using grunt. However it return all the rows. Not sure if there is way to get specific rows from cassandra

I have a table:

```
create table home
{
   id primary,
   age int,
   name String
};
```

There are three records
1, 10, Tom
2, 5,  Harry
3, 20, James

I want to return the data whose age>10 using pig grunt (accessing cassandra database)

Example :

```
rows = LOAD 'cassandra://Keyspace1/home?page_size=5&where_clause=age+%3D+3&use_secondary=true' USING CassandraStorage();
```

Is it possible to achieve this? I tried cql but it fails from pig grunt.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can only use where clauses on indexed columns.